# Passing data between two components in two modules without service.ts in angular

Tags: angular

How to pass data between two components where two components in two different modules.

I have two modules.
1. IssueModule
2. RuleModule
From Rule Module component i am navigating to create issue(IssueModule) component.
i need to pass large amount of data to be pass from rule module to issue module.
I am not supposed to use a Service.ts to pass data in between components.

i have used below in my rulecomponent.ts

```
this.router.navigate(
  [ISSUE_ROUTES_NAMES.ISSUES + '/' + ISSUE_ROUTES_NAMES.CREATE],
  { 
    state: { 
      queryParams: { 
        pname: this.pname, 
        pid: this.pid 
      }, 
      selectedModels: {
        'some data here'
      } 
    } 
  }
);
```

I am able to read the data in issuecomponent.ts as below

```
this.state = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(() => window.history.state));
```

But the challenge is i am losing the data after page refresh/reload from state.
one more challenge is how to set queryparams to current route with out changing route.

Please let me know anyone can answer.

Comment: As it's a good practice, why aren't you supposed to use services?

Comment: MY TL won't accept using services to pass data, i am not able to convey him

Comment: you can use localStorage

Comment: using localstorage in our app is like crime

Comment: you should be using a service. Since service gets re-instantiated on page refresh, consider setting the required data from a common parent of the two routes